# Scan a table with AWS DynamoDB SDK for Java 2.x

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I have a table (`users`) in Amazon DynamoDB with items like this:

```
{
   id: "ef1e44bc-03ad-11e9-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1", // UUID, HASH key
   version: "3.1",                             // Version string, conforming to semver standards
   emailsEnabled: true,                        // Boolean flag
   capabilities: {                             // Big nested object, not important for the question
      …
   }
}
```

I want to run an ad-hoc scan to tell how many users with version 3.1 have emails enabled. I don't have any indexes here for this table but it's ok to do a scan.

How do I do that with [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-java-2-x-released/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use [Filter Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression) to limit the amount of data processed by your app.

You can also get rid of additional, unimportant, attributes in scan results by using [ProjectionExpressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html).

Here is the code:

```
DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder().build();
ScanRequest request =
    ScanRequest
        .builder()
        .tableName("users")
        .filterExpression("version = :version")
        .expressionAttributeValues(
            Map.of(":version", AttributeValue.builder().s("3.1").build()) // Using Java 9+ Map.of
        )
        .projectionExpression("id, version, emailsEnabled")
        .build();
ScanIterable response = client.scanPaginator(request);

for (ScanResponse page : response) {
    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : page.items()) {
        // Consume the item
        System.out.println(item);

        if (item.get("emailsEnabled").bool()) {
            // Update counters
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a filter expression is applied after a scan finishes, but before the results are returned. Therefore, a scan will consume the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present or not.